# Trouble using a subquery in Ecto

Tags: postgresql, phoenix-framework, ecto

Given the following messages table:

```
     Column      |            Type             |
-----------------+-----------------------------+-
 id              | integer                     |
 body            | text                        |
 conversation_id | integer                     |
 user_id         | integer                     |
 inserted_at     | timestamp without time zone |
 updated_at      | timestamp without time zone |
 sid             | character varying(255)      |
 status          | character varying(255)      |
```

I'm trying to create the following SQL query in Ecto:

```
SELECT COUNT(conversation_id) FROM messages m1 WHERE m1.id = ANY(SELECT MAX(m2.id) FROM messages m2 GROUP BY m2.conversation_id) AND status = 'received';
```

I tried:

```
query = Message
  |> where([m], m.id in fragment("ANY(select max(m2.id) from messages m2 group by m2.conversation_id)") and m.status = "received")
  |> select([m], count(m.conversation_id))
```

But I'm getting a runtime error:

```
** (Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol Ecto.Queryable not implemented for BlackMamba.Resolver.Message, the given module is not queryable
       (ecto) lib/ecto/queryable.ex:33: Ecto.Queryable.Atom.to_query/1
       (ecto) lib/ecto/query/builder/filter.ex:46: Ecto.Query.Builder.Filter.apply/3
(black_mamba) web/resolver/conversation.ex:56: BlackMamba.Resolver.Conversation.needs_response_conversation_count/2
```

Any tips are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used `fragment/1` but as the error message says the first argument (the one you're passing is `sql_fragment`) must be a keyword list (lists like this `[abc: 1, def: 2]`) and you are passing a string.

Ecto sanitizes all raw SQL to prevent SQL Injection.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please see my updated question. I've gotten a little farther. I was just about to update it when you answered.

Comment: @CarlYoungblood Does your Message model use Ecto.Schema? The error message would suggest it does not.

Comment: Thanks @Gazler. Turned out the model was aliased to something different than I thought. After fixing this, things worked ok.